# CSS div hide if input is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I need your help.
If `.radios .mevcut input ~ #checks` is clicked, show the div.
How can I display none on the `checks` div.

```css
.radios .mevcut input~#checks {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radios">
  <h4>Proje Türü</h4>
  <input type="radio" id="statik" checked="checked" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
  <label for="statik">Statik Proje</label>
  <input type="radio" id="fenni" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="fenni">Fenni Mesuliyet</label>
  <div class="mevcut">
    <input type="radio" id="mevcut" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="mevcut">Mevcut Yapı</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checks" id="checks">
  <h4>Hizmet Bölümleri:</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-oneri-raporu" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
  <label for="checks-oneri-raporu">Öneri Raporu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-on-proje" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="checks-on-proje">Ön Proje</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-uyg-projesi" checked="checked" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
  <label for="checks-uyg-projesi">Uygulama Projesi ve Detayları</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-metraj" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="checks-metraj">Metraj[Kalıp,Demir,Beton,Duvar]</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-celik" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
  <label for="checks-celik">Çelik</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this with css can be complicated. You can try to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Okey bro eyw kirve baştacısın.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve.
As far as I understand you are trying to show the checkboxes, if any of the radios is checked. This is not possible with HTML and CSS alone with your HTML structure

For the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`) you need to have the regarding element (or children thereof) to be siblings, i.e. they share the same parent element

```css
.radios .checks input[type=checkbox],
.radios .checks input[type=checkbox] + label{
  display: none;
}
.radios input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .checks input[type=checkbox],
.radios input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .checks input[type=checkbox] + label {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="radios">

  <h4>Proje Türü</h4>
  <input type="radio" id="statik" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
  <label for="statik">Statik Proje</label>
  <input type="radio" id="fenni" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="fenni">Fenni Mesuliyet</label>
  <input type="radio" id="mevcut" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
  <label for="mevcut">Mevcut Yapı</label>
  <div class="checks" id="checks">
    <h4>Hizmet Bölümleri:</h4>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-oneri-raporu" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
    <label for="checks-oneri-raporu">Öneri Raporu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-on-proje" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
    <label for="checks-on-proje">Ön Proje</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-uyg-projesi" checked="checked" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="checks-uyg-projesi">Uygulama Projesi ve Detayları</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-metraj" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
    <label for="checks-metraj">Metraj[Kalıp,Demir,Beton,Duvar]</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-celik" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="checks-celik">Çelik</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to try the opposite, e.g. Hide the Checkboxes, if any radio is checked

```css
.radios .checks input[type=checkbox],
.radios .checks input[type=checkbox] + label{
  display: inline;
}
.radios input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .checks input[type=checkbox],
.radios input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .checks input[type=checkbox] + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radios">

  <h4>Proje Türü</h4>
  <input type="radio" id="statik" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
  <label for="statik">Statik Proje</label>
  <input type="radio" id="fenni" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="fenni">Fenni Mesuliyet</label>
  <input type="radio" id="mevcut" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
  <label for="mevcut">Mevcut Yapı</label>
  <div class="checks" id="checks">
    <h4>Hizmet Bölümleri:</h4>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-oneri-raporu" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
    <label for="checks-oneri-raporu">Öneri Raporu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-on-proje" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
    <label for="checks-on-proje">Ön Proje</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-uyg-projesi" checked="checked" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="checks-uyg-projesi">Uygulama Projesi ve Detayları</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-metraj" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
    <label for="checks-metraj">Metraj[Kalıp,Demir,Beton,Duvar]</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-celik" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="checks-celik">Çelik</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to hede the checkboxes, if the last radio is checked

```css
.radios .checks input[type=checkbox],
.radios .checks input[type=checkbox] + label{
  display: inline;
}
.radios #mevcut:checked ~ .checks input[type=checkbox],
.radios #mevcut:checked ~ .checks input[type=checkbox] + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radios">

  <h4>Proje Türü</h4>
  <input type="radio" id="statik" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
  <label for="statik">Statik Proje</label>
  <input type="radio" id="fenni" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="fenni">Fenni Mesuliyet</label>
  <input type="radio" id="mevcut" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
  <label for="mevcut">Mevcut Yapı</label>
  <div class="checks" id="checks">
    <h4>Hizmet Bölümleri:</h4>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-oneri-raporu" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
    <label for="checks-oneri-raporu">Öneri Raporu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-on-proje" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
    <label for="checks-on-proje">Ön Proje</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-uyg-projesi" checked="checked" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="checks-uyg-projesi">Uygulama Projesi ve Detayları</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-metraj" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
    <label for="checks-metraj">Metraj[Kalıp,Demir,Beton,Duvar]</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checks-celik" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="checks-celik">Çelik</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

More detailed explanation

Your structure looks like this

```
.radios
    h4
    input#statik
    label
    input#fenni
    .mevcut
        input#mevcut <-- If this is checked --------------+
        label                                             |
.checks                                                   |
    h4                                                    |
    input#checks-oneri-raporu            ----+            |
    label                                    |            |
    input#checks-on-proje                    |            |
    label                                    |------------|
    input#checks-uyg-projesi                 |            
    label                                    |  These should be hidden          
    input#checks-metraj                      |            
    label                                    |            
    input#checks-celik                       |            
    label                                ----+
```

The selector
`.radios .mevcut input ~ #checks`
won't work, because `#checks` is not a sibling of `.radios .mevcut input`

Answer (score 1):

Just as @yunzen stated in his answer:

> For the general sibling combinator (~) you need to have the regarding element (or children thereof) to be siblings, i.e. they share the same parent element

which means the two elements have to be on same level under same parent, so if you can modify the HTML code his answer is great.

Otherwise you need JavaScript

```js
theOptions = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

theOptions.forEach((opt) => {
  opt.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const displayValue = opt.getAttribute("id") === "mevcut" ? "none" : "block";
    document.getElementById("checks").style.display = displayValue;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="radios">
  <h4>Proje Türü</h4>
  <input type="radio" id="statik" checked="checked" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
  <label for="statik">Statik Proje</label>
  <input type="radio" id="fenni" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="fenni">Fenni Mesuliyet</label>
  <div class="mevcut">
    <input type="radio" id="mevcut" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
    <label for="mevcut">Mevcut Yapı</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checks" id="checks">
  <h4>Hizmet Bölümleri:</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-oneri-raporu" name="projeturu" value="statikproje">
  <label for="checks-oneri-raporu">Öneri Raporu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-on-proje" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="checks-on-proje">Ön Proje</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-uyg-projesi" checked="checked" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
  <label for="checks-uyg-projesi">Uygulama Projesi ve Detayları</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-metraj" name="projeturu" value="fenniproje">
  <label for="checks-metraj">Metraj[Kalıp,Demir,Beton,Duvar]</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checks-celik" name="projeturu" value="mevcutyapi">
  <label for="checks-celik">Çelik</label>
</div>
```